# I get an Error JNA while trying to run my java program from CLI

Tags: java, javac

I get this error when trying to run my program from CLI:

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: daniel has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I have Windows 10
Already tried updating the path following these steps:

1. Search for Advanced System Settings in your windows Search box. Click on Advanced System Settings.
2. Click on Environment variables button: Environment Variables popup will open.
3. Go to system variables session, and click on New button to create new variable (HOME_PATH), then New System Variables popup will open.
4. Give Variable Name: JAVA_HOME, and Variable value : Your Java SDK home path. Ex: C:\Profram files\java\jdk1.8.0_151 Note: It should not include \bin. Then click on OK button.
5. Now you are able to see your JAVA_HOME in system variables list.
6. Select Path (from system variables list) and click on Edit button, A new pop will opens (Edit Environment Variables). It was introduced in windows 10.
7. Click on New button and give %JAVA_HOME%\bin at highlighted field and click Ok button.

Didn't work, also tried uninstalling the JDK and reinstalling but same issue, I installed the JDK from this link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Any clue?

Comment: what's the output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

Class file version 58.0 belongs to java 14 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)).

You need to use java 14, instead of java 8 to run your program.
Alternatively you could compile your project using java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Mmhm I remember I tried version 14 but uninstalled then installed Java 8, not sure if that created a conclict.

Also I can use Eclipse and it runs fine, but I want to try using CLI

java -version gives:

java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)